# How to sign debug APK's with the same key as release APK's - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, signing

I want to test in-app purchasing within my app, but it seems impossible to do this with a regular debug APK through Android Studio? Has anyone done this before and if so what steps did you take to do it?

I was thinking to get around it I should try signing my debug APK's in the same way I sign my release APK's. How can I do this?

Comment: Two alternatives: 1) test with the release version or 2) create another build type for testing your In App Purchases.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further on each of these options? Especially the second one as that sounds promising. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

You can config that in your android studio, right click your project, chose the ***open module settings***

Or if you are crazy about the hand-writen build scripts, here is a snapshot of code:

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".keystore")
      storePassword "${storePassword}"
      keyAlias "${keyAlias}"
      keyPassword "${keyPassword}"
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

Just config your debug and release build type with same **signingConfig**.

Comment: Note for the OP: if you are using version control, you should not add your credentials directly to the `build.gradle` file. Instead you should put them in a properties file which is not added to version control.

Comment: Yeah, we can't do stupid things like: commit our key store's name and password to code repo; or commit our certificate key store into our code repo.